# Macs create invisible files when connecting to Ubuntu-server via AFP

Tags: 14.04, networking, mac, adobe, smb

This topic has also been posted in the Adobe Forum, since I do not expect this to be a Linux issue, I just want to make sure that is the case.

We have just setup a Linux Server (Ubuntu - 14.04.3LTS) to which both Windows and Mac machines connects without any problems.
The only issue is, that when saving files from Illustrator, using AFP from the macs, the files created are invisible.
This means, that you cannot see the files, when browsing the server from Illustrator, nor is it possible to insert pictures directly into an Illustrator-file, since it is not visible.
When view invisible-files are turned on in Finder on the mac, you can see and access them without any problems, but again not from Illustrator.
Old files does not have this problem, it is only new files created by the mac-users.
This happens when using Adobe Illustrator version CC2014, we have then installed a version 2015, but the problem still occurs.
The Mac clients are all running 10.10.3.

We have read both these threads, but since they are old and does not include the same software, as we are using, we have not been able to extract any information from those.

Indesign/Illustrator writes hidden PDFs on afp shared volume

BUG?? Saving files in Illustrator to an AFP network share

Does anyone have an idea of what happens, and what a solution could be.
We have tested the server very thoroughly, and it does not seem to be where the problem originates.

I have just been informed by my technician, that this also happens with the rest of the Adobe CC programs.
On top of that, if the file is copied to the server, it is visible.

Kind Regards
Charlotte

Comment: This sounds like a Mac problem to me...

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your reply.
We have gotten a bit further, and have now found out, that the problem lies within the netatalk protocol. 
We have managed to solve it on a SMB-connection, by force create mode and force directory mode. Is there anyway the same can be done to the afp.conf?

Comment: Yes @charlie_feilberg I saw a mention in the manual to this related to Linux/Unix ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `invisible dots = no` in your `afp config`. Worked for me.

For Reference:[Question about invisible dots ?](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.network.netatalk.user/21929)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 normal exceptions

1. files beginning with a "." are considered hidden by file explorers (including command line).
2. files whose name are inside a file ".hidden" are considered hidden by Nautilus.

Besides that when a file has no permissions it will not be shown. That could be a problem related to configuration: you need to tell the software you use to create files on another filesystem with specific permissions. If those are set wrong it could lead to problems.

Under "volume options" in the manual:

> **invisible dots = BOOLEAN (default: no) (V)**
>
> make dot files invisible. WARNING: enabling this option will lead to unwanted side effects were OS X applications when saving files to a
>   temporary file starting with a dot first, **then renaming the temp file
>   to its final name, result in the saved file being invisible**. The only
>   thing this option is useful for is making files that start with a dot
>   invisible on Mac OS 9. It's completely useless on Mac OS X, as both in
>   Finder and in Terminal files starting with a dot are hidden anyway.

---

Regarding [apt.conf](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.0/htmldocs/afp.conf.5.html) I saw this mentioned and it states your problem I would assume:

> Options for ACL handling
>
> By default, the effective permission of the authenticated user are
>   only mapped to the mentioned UARights permission structure, **not the
>   UNIX mode**. You can adjust this behaviour with the configuration option
>   mac acls:
>
> map acls = none|rights|mode (G)
>
> ```
> none    no mapping of ACLs 
> rights  effective permissions are mapped to UARights structure. This is the default.
> mode    ACLs are additionally mapped to the UNIX mode of the filesystem object.
> ```

You will need "mode".

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, i've found that setting the unix priv on the share, sovled the problem for me. (The problem only occurred on OS X - and in Illustrator/InDesign)

> unix priv = BOOLEAN (default: yes) (V) Whether to use AFP3 UNIX
>   privileges. This should be set for OS X clients. See also: file perm,
>   directory perm and umask.

Comment: to what did you set it? To NO on specific share?